# Trouble understanding parts of this code using for-loops?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class PA4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int line = 1; line <= 6; line++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (line - 1); j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.print(line);
        for (int j = (line + 1); j <= 6; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

This code produces this output:

1.....

.2....

..3...

...4..

....5.

.....6

I understand the first loop and how it prints the dots by subtracting one from each line but I can't understand how the second loop works and how it prints the dots, or how assigning "j" the value of "line + 1" does whatever it's doing.

Comment: try sorting out your indentation first.

Comment: The code is indented wrong from just above `System.out.print(line);`. Re-formatting it should make the code clear.

Comment: In plain English, the first loop is printing out `N` dots, where `N` is the line number.  Then, it prints the line number `N` itself, and finally loops again to print however many remaining dots are needed.  Just try tracing through your code line by line until it is clear.

Comment: I'm not sure how it should be indented.

Comment: (There was an approved edit that removed the indentation problems, and therefore the question became pointless. I have rolled it back.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is clearer; it does the same thing.

```
public class PA4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int line = 1; line <= 6; line++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                if (j == line)
                    System.out.print(line);
                else
                    System.out.print(".");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Your inner portion (two loops plus), together, always count up to 6, printing dots and one number.  But they do it by counting up to line-1, then printing the number, then printing more dots, counting from just after the number up to 6.  I've done it above in a single loop, but it's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I can only use for-loops for this exercise. I haven't learned about using "if" and "else" yet.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected indentation

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 6; line++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= (line - 1); j++) {
        System.out.print(".");
    }
    System.out.print(line);
    for (int j = (line + 1); j <= 6; j++) {
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

replacing with a hard-coded value

```
// for three it would be
for (int j = 1; j <= (2); j++) {  // personally I would do j < 3
    System.out.print(".");
}
System.out.print(3);
for (int j = (4); j <= 6; j++) {
    System.out.print(".");
}
System.out.println();
```

**output**

```
..3...
```

Comment: It's easier to understand when you use hard-coded values, but I'm still lost on how "j = (line + 1); j <= 6; j++" prints out the dots after the numbers. I just started learning to code and nothing has clicked yet for me, though I haven't studied all that much.

Comment: so for values 1&2 it ptints dots, then it prints 3, then for values 4to6 it prints more dots